# How to write a full time in strtotime?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, strtotime

I'm trying to get the timestamp for:"hour:minute am/pm month/day/year" but it doesn't seem to be working properly. What order does it need to be in?

Example of my current order:
11:59 am, 04/19/2012

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to know what the date format string needs to look like?

Comment: Do you want time from 11:59 am, 04/19/2012? or else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you convert the asked formatted date/time string into a timestamp:

```
$date_string = '11:59 am, 04/19/2012';
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i a, m/d/Y", $date_string);
$timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
echo $timestamp;
```

Output:

```
1334833140
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to use the procedural way, you can call `date_create_from_format` instead of `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Answer (score 2):

Put the date before the time:

```
echo strtotime('04/19/2012 11:59 am');
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would be similar to this

```
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

So the order is

year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds

I'm also assuming strtotime is smart enough to know different date formats so you should be fine with your date format, just put it as the first part and the time after it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the following character after am: **,**

For example use this:

```
strtotime("11:59 am 04/19/2012")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the string you need to parse to `date()` to get the format you want from a timestamp is this:

```
date("H:i a, m/d/Y", $timestamp);
```

More formatting characters can be found in the documentation, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

---

`strtotime()` won't convert the date format you've given into a timestamp, however the more powerful and versatile [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class might be able to.